# Problems Setting up an Ubuntu / Linux Router

Tags: linux, router, nat

I have an Ubuntu linux box that I want to turn into a router. It has 2 NICs, and will sit between i) a cable modem (the internet) and ii) a wireless router (serving an internal network). With this simple setup, I've been able to get some distance, but seem to be tripping up below.

```
(the net) cable modem   ->  (eth3) ubuntu box (eth1)    ->  linksys wifi router
```

[ok] ubuntu dhcp client (using eth3) can connect to modem and surf the net 
[ok] ubuntu can statically assign an IP to internal NIC (eth1) with command:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

[ok] can install and run DHCP server. Client machines can get IPs and ping ubuntu.

**After this, is when things start to go awry:** 
[x] after a while ubuntu eth3 keeps its IP address, but can no longer connect to the net. Rebooting (calling 'dhclient' again) puts me back online.
[x] ubuntu eth1 either i) loses 192.168.1.1 IP address when a client asks for a new IP lease or ii) gets assigned 192.168.1.100 (the start of the network range in '/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf' - see below). How can I keep this value steady?

/etc/default/dhcp3-server

```
INTERFACES="eth1"
```

/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf

```
ddns-update-style none; 
log-facility local7; 
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.200;
  option domain-name-servers 64.71.255.198;
  option domain-name "frye.com";
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

[x] I'm having problems making the ubuntu box NAT packets from client machines (eth1) to the net (eth3). I've tried setting up the tables with the below commands (I've also tried reversing the NICs in the commands). '/etc/sysctl.conf' (and corresponding '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward') have the expected value of '1'. What's the correct incantation for forwarding packets from eth1 -> eth3 ?

```
sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth3 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

I'm sure there's just some config magic that I'm missing on both these points.

Thanks for any help 
Tim

Comment: sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely setting this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Some random hints:

Don't use `ifconfig` directly to configure your NICs. Instead, put the config into `/etc/network/interfaces`, e.g.:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Your `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf` appears to have a typo in the `broadcast-address` (should be 192.168.**1**.255).

Your `iptables` MASQUERADE rule should probably be more specific. It may be matching packets that should not be NAT'ed. I would add a source match for the internal network, like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth3 -j MASQUERADE
```

Your ACCEPT rule on the FORWARD chain should not be needed, provided that the policy on the FORWARD chain is ACCEPT (which is the default).

Comment: Badda boom, badda bing !! That did it.